# How can I verify if a typescript file contains decorators with a regex?

Tags: regex, typescript, typescript-decorator

I would like to check if a typescript file contains a decorated function or class without compiling it. Is there a regex or something equally fast that can detect if a typescript file contains a decorated class or function?

Answer (score 1):

You can parse the file with a [typescript parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript-parser). This will generate an AST (Abstract Syntax Tree) for you. From the resulting AST you can check if any decorators have been used in the file.

To go further into this, you can use the `@typescript-eslint/parser` parser for this, and its parse method.

```
// requires ES6+
import { parse } from '@typescript-eslint/parser';

const code = '@Component({key: "value"}) class Hello {}';

const ast = parse(code);

console.log(JSON.stringify(ast));
```

This returns you the following AST:

```
{
  "type": "Program",
  "body": [
    {
      "type": "ClassDeclaration",
      "id": { "type": "Identifier", "name": "Hello" },
      "body": { "type": "ClassBody", "body": [] },
      "superClass": null,
      "decorators": [
        {
          "type": "Decorator",
          "expression": {
            "type": "CallExpression",
            "callee": { "type": "Identifier", "name": "Component" },
            "arguments": [
              {
                "type": "ObjectExpression",
                "properties": [
                  {
                    "type": "Property",
                    "key": { "type": "Identifier", "name": "key" },
                    "value": {
                      "type": "Literal",
                      "value": "value",
                      "raw": "\"value\""
                    },
                    "computed": false,
                    "method": false,
                    "shorthand": false,
                    "kind": "init"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ],
            "optional": false
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "sourceType": "script"
}
```

The parse function also has multiple options, e.g. you can turn the range option to find out where exactly in the code the decorator is: `parse(code, {range: true})`

Answer (score 0):

As suggested already, you could examine the AST. Here is an example of how you could do it: [link](https://astexplorer.net/#/gist/3134a3adfc1c0e122184b85accb94104/76ba041fa08460b854da48d4c1d9a8e25ec3a01c). See the console for the two decorators identified.

The babel based visitor

```
export default function (babel) {
  const { types: t } = babel;
  
  return {
    visitor: {
      Identifier(path) {
        if(t.isDecorator(path.parent)) {
            console.log(path.node.name + " is a decorator")
        }
      }
    }
  };
}
```